# how to read VARRAY with C++ and OCCI 'execute' method?

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

i am struggling to read a VARRAY element from oracle 11g database.
i am using CPP occi DLL.
i can read any other types, and update VARRAY type, but when I try to select VARRAY value, i get an 'access violation' exception in the occi dll :(

here is a simplified scenario:

```
CREATE TYPE ALIST AS VARRAY(50) OF NUMBER(8)

create table ATABLE (a number(8), b alist)

insert into mytable values(1, alist(1,2,3))
```

when i do

```
oc::Statement* stmt = m_cConnection->createStatement("SELECT b FROM ATABLE");
stmt->executeQuery();
```

it's OK
but when i try to access the VARRAY the same way

```
oc::Statement* stmt = m_cConnection->createStatement("SELECT a FROM ATABLE");
stmt->executeQuery();
```

i get

> First-chance exception at 0x0094a46d in OracleTester.exe: 0xC0000005:
> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000120.

any idea what i am doing wrong? maybe i need to use different API to get VARRAY data ? or do some preparations?

any hint will be appreciated...

Comment: Do you know of OTT utility? It can generate C++ class representations of database object types for you. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/objects.htm#LNCPP20197

Comment: i saw this in the docs, but, i since i am not a DB expert, and even less expert in oracle, i just followed the simplest driver installation, which is instantclient, and i can't see this utility in the installation folder.
anyone know where to download from?

Comment: well, i've played with OTT, without success :( the only examples i can find are for VARRAY within object, which is not my case (can't change the db schema)